# Call undefined function getip() error thrown after hosting into server

Tags: php

I have developed a website with social login like google, facebook. I hosted my website in server. When hitting home page in browser '**Fatal error: Call to undefined function getip() in header.php on line 35**' error is thrown. But actually line35 in header.php file contains only html tags. How do i find where the error is actually. Thanks in advance.

I have developed a blog with php version 5.5
Hosted server php running version is 5.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `getip()` called anywhere in header.php?

Comment: no. i did not called anywhere in my project. @emily.